# What is the simplest objective c unit test that you can create and execute from the commandline?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I am using a Mac and would like to create a simple objective c unit test file to try out with a continuous build process. What is the simplest unit test file that I can create that I can point xcodebuild at to execute from the terminal?

```
//Simple file
//with some setup and a simple assert equal statement

> xcodebuild ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple OCUnit test file might look like this (in a SimpleTests.m file)

```
@interface SimpleTests : SenTestCase {}
@end
@implementation SimpleTests
- (void)testFail { STFail(@"Tests are running"); }
@end
```

I've no idea if it is the simplest (and don't really want to know, thanks). It's certainly simple enough.

However, to get it to do anything you must build it into a framework that links against SenTestingKit and Foundation frameworks -  so having your simple test file isn't really half the problem.

This might help

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html

If you go with xCodeBuild you obviously need a complete XCode project, properly setup, inorder to build the framework. You could not really describe this as a simple, single file solution that you can build and execute.

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what unit testing framework you choose to use.  Creating a file with OCUnit should be the simplest since the framework is built into Xcode, and Xcode ships with templates for creating test files.  You should be able to create a new OCUnit target from template, and then add an OCUnit file from template to that target.  At that point you should be able to *xcodebuild* that target and be done.

That said, it's been a while since I used OCUnit, and I found using it from the command line and in our CI builds to be frustrating.

It's not built into Xcode, but [Cedar](http://github.com/pivotal/Cedar) has [templates](http://github.com/pivotal/CedarTemplates) for creating new projects and files in Xcode.  I wrapped up the *xcodebuild* command line in a Rakefile to make running from the command line easier.  You **should** be able to create a new Cedar spec project from template and run it, but I see now that I've forgotten to include the Rakefile in the template.  This should work if you get the templates sometime later today.

The Rakefile is for rake, which is a ruby version of make, in case you haven't used it.  You can install it easily with

```
$ gem install rake
```

and then simply invoke tasks by name:

```
$ rake specs
```